# send data to a new jsp page when user click on a row

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, jstl

```
<form action="" method="get" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">

        <h3>Current Users</h3>
         <c:if test="${!empty userList}">
        <table class="data" id="results"   border="1"  >
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Last Seen</th>

        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${userList}" var="user">
         <tr onmouseover="ChangeColor(this, true);" 
              onmouseout="ChangeColor(this, false);" 
              onclick="DoNav('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/secure/detailUserView');">
            <td>${user.name}</td>
            <td>${user.email}</td>
            <td>${user.create_date}</td> 
        </tr> >
        </c:forEach>
        </table>
        </c:if>
        <div id="pageNavPosition"></div>

      </form>
```

Now what i want is to send the user information to a new jsp page when user click on a particular row. how can i do it please suggest

Romi.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

You can use forms to submit data. The values on the  tags will be submitted as request params to the url specified in the form's action.